# Writing to a MemoryStream via a StringWriter adds null characters to stream

Tags: c#, .net-4.8

I have some code in C# where I am trying to write to a MemoryStream via a StringWriter example code:

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
  using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter())
  {
    writer.WriteLine("SELECT");
    writer.WriteLine("\tT.*");
    writer.WriteLine("FROM");
    writer.WriteLine("\t[A Table] T");
    writer.WriteLine("WHERE");
    writer.WriteLine($"\tT.[Data Field] IN ({data})");
  }

   ....
  return new MemoryStream(stream.GetBuffer());
}
```

When I inspect the contents of `stream` I see that the .NET Framework has added extra `0` bytes to the end of the buffer to take it up to 256 bytes. I can not find anything in the MSDN help and it is puzzling.

To work around this (using the above example) I did the following:

```
string crlf = Environment.NewLine;


string value = $"SELECT{crlf}";
value += $"\tT.*{crlf}";
value += $"FROM{crlf}";
value += $"\t[A Table] T{crlf}";
value += $"WHERE{crlf}";
value += $"\tT.[Data Field] IN ({data})";


return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value));
```

I would rather use a stream writer than to build up a string and then call `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value)`

I have tried using a StringBuilder as an intermediary step but it still adds the extra characters to the end.

Comment: You should probably look at the documentation for `MemoryStream`. Especially to compare and contrast `GetBuffer` and `ToArray`.

Comment: Side note, this looks like you're building an SQL Query using string concatenation. Highly consider parametrized statements.

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @gunr2171 Normally I would use a parameterized query just in this use case I am building a query to select data and the source table and field is unknown at compile time. The code is only example code to describe my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `stream.GetBuffer()`, which returns the underlying buffer the stream writes to - which is almost always larger than the stream. The buffer is expanded automatically when a write would go past the end of it.

You can either use `stream.GetBuffer()` but *also* take the stream length into account, and effectively ignore any bytes past that - or call `stream.ToArray()` instead to get a copy of *just the valid data* as a new byte array.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it would be something daft. I don't have enough points to up vote this answer.